# spark parallelize writes using list of dataframes

Tags: apache-spark

I have a list of dataframe created using jdbc. Is there a way to write them in parallel using parquet?

```
val listOfTableNameAndDf = for {
  table <- tableNames
} yield (table, sqlContext.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, table,  new Properties))
```

I can write them sequentially, but is there a way to parallelize the writes or make it faster.

```
listOfTableNameAndDf.map { x => {
  x._2.write.mode(org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(getStatingDir(x._1)) 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can future to perform write actions asynchronously:

```scala
dfs.map { case (name, table) => 
  Future(table.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(getStatingDir("name")))
}
```

but I doubt it will result in any significant improvement. In case like yours there a few main bottlenecks:

- Cluster resources - if any job saturates available resources remaining jobs will be queued as before.
- Input source throughput - source database have to keep up with the cluster.
- Output source IO - output source have to keep with the cluster.

If source and output are the same for each job, jobs will compete for the same set of resources and sequential execution of the driver code is almost never an issue.

If you're looking for improvements in the current code I would recommend starting with using reader method with a following signature:

```scala
jdbc(url: String, table: String, columnName: String, 
  lowerBound: Long, upperBound: Long, numPartitions: Int, 
  connectionProperties: Properties)
```

It requires more effort to use but typically exhibits much better performance because reads (and as a result data) are distributed between worker nodes.